# PHP file upload: Read raw file data

Tags: php, upload

As far as I know `$_FILES["fieldname"]["size"]` contains the file size *after* the file has been uploaded.

In Perl, you can read the raw file data very easy chunk-wise and that way determine if the file is too big *before* it has been fully uploaded.

Is there an easy way to do just the same in `PHP`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514166/check-file-size-before-upload

Comment: Nope. Your PHP script is only _started_ when the upload to the server is already complete.

Comment: how does the file gets to the server? if you use a html-formular you could limit the filesize via html attribute `maxlength`, which limits the number of bytes of the input...

Comment: I already check the file size on the client side. However, I thought it would be nice if you could discard the fileupload if a certain number of bytes has been exceeded. Okay, my file upload is for small pictures, can I somehow set an individual max file size in php.ini for a paticular script?

Comment: The basic problem is that the HTTP connection and upload are handled by the web server, not by PHP code. You have http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php, but this needs to be invoked explicitly by a separate HTTP request. You could use a script which attaches to a port and explicitly handles HTTP connections "manually", which gives you full freedom, but is probably overkill. If you goal is to simply limit the maximum upload size, there's an .ini setting for that though in both PHP and your web server.

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340566/check-file-type-flv-before-php-upload-file-in-temporary-folder-by-reading-only).

Comment: @deceze: Yes, I thought I'd write an Perl/FastCGI app for the file upload, but it would be in fact overkill, given its purpose (file upload for small pictures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the max size in the `php.ini` config file, but **it will affect all your file uploads** :

```
upload_max_filesize 10M
```

If you're using a `.htaccess` file, you can also write like that :

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
```

Take a look at the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach the file on the client from the server without copying it. What you can do is inspect the file using javascript on the client side, and decide then whether to upload or not.

Basically, read your file into a FileReader, and check the size attribute.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4307882/326154 has some good answers.

Comment: How can you inspect a file on filesystem via javascript?

Comment: @Jurik: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514166/check-file-size-before-upload