# How is it possible to get the name of PHP's currently uploading file's temp name

Tags: php, lamp

As all of us know, PHP finishes the upload and the enables you to use `move_uploaded_file()`; before this, however, it creates a temp file and then does the job. I want to know is it possible to get the name of this uploaded file during the file upload and before populating it into `$_FILES`?

I want to get the upload progress, while `$_SESSION` and Javascript `onprogress` solution both suck..

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to do?

Comment: so can you say how? I need to impose some operations

Comment: of course while the upload is in progress

Comment: I believe this is platform dependant. On LA[M]P modularized systems you can inspect the `/proc/<PID of relevant Apache instance>/fd/*` directory. In general, you can't. Perhaps you can explain why you need this in more detail; there may be alternative ways of getting the same result.

Comment: Now we're going somewhere. Why does session (http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) suck? Maybe you can change the interface and make it suck less, and still have a portable solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check file type (FLV) before PHP upload file in temporary folder by reading only starting 3 bytes of file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340566/check-file-type-flv-before-php-upload-file-in-temporary-folder-by-reading-only)

Answer (score 2):

`$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` is the filename. It is not possible in `PHP` (without using ugly tricks) to get the filename before the upload is finished.

To do this, you have to fallback on either Flash (uploadify) or CGI (Perl / Python / C++ / Other)

Comment: I can use python (CGI), but then how is it possible? If say, perl and python do the same

Comment: Yes they are the same, Perl was just as example. I'm not confident enough with CGI using Python to be more specific sorry.

Comment: The *process* of course knows the name of the temporary file; the problem lies in *you* accessing that information. If the platform has an API for letting you, all well and good. If it hasn't, your last recourse is some kind of hack, such as the `/proc` trick.

Answer (score 0):

A "reliable" progress bar, which seems to be your goal, will always require some sort of server **and** client support. In its most general and portable instance, PHP will see only the completed upload and you'll get no progress bar, but only the filled `$_FILES` structure.

On some platforms the information can be garnered from the system itself. For example under Linux/Apache you can inspect what temporary files Apache has opened in the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem, where available; so you need to put in the requisites "Linux, Apache, php5_module, /proc".

You can use a dedicated POST endpoint that does *not* terminate on the Web server, but on a specially crafted uploader process (I worked on a Perl script doing this years ago; I recall it used POE, and the architecture):

```
POST (from browser) ==> (server, proxying) ==> UPLOADER

The uploader immediately echoes a crafted GET to the server, activating
a PHP "pre-upload" page, and then might call a progress GET URL periodically
to update the upload status. When completed, it would issue a pseudo POST
to PHP "almost" as if it came from the client, sending $_POST['_FILES']
instead of $_FILES.
```

[The `$_SESSION` solution](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) is a good compromise but relies on the server not doing buffering.

A better and more "modern" solution would be to leverage the *chunked upload* AJAX trick and get resumable uploads, reliable progress and large file support all in one nifty package. See for example [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375852/file-uploads-how-to-utilize-chunking). Now you get wider server support but the solution won't work on some older browsers.

You could offer the user the choice between old-style FILE upload, Flash uploader (which bypasses all problems as it doesn't rely on the browser but on Flash code), Java FTP upload control (same thing, but sometimes with some protocol and firewall issues since it doesn't use HTTP as the container web page does), and AJAX HTML5 chunking, possibly based on browser capabilities.

I.e., a user with IE6 would see a form saying

```
SORRY!
Your browser does not support large file uploads and progress bar.
To send a file of no more than XXX meg,
[                    ] [Choose file...]  [ >> BEGIN UPLOAD >>> ]
```